# Getting foreach to store its return value in a 3d array

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, foreach, doparallel

I have a function which returns a (numVals x N) array/matrix. This function needs to be evaluated K times. My goal is to store all results in a multidimensional array containing doubles with shape c(numVals, N, K).

I'm having trouble finding appropriate arguments for .combine (or other parameters of foreach) so that its return value is in the correct format. I realize I could just go ahead and reshape a 2d returned by foreach later, but I am kind of running into memory limitations (and I'm not sure I can reshape in-place without any memory overhead.

The solution I'm looking for can be either foreach (or similar function compatible with dopar) outputting a 3d or reshaping into correct format without having to create another object with memory footprint as large as results.

Here's a code snippet:

```
library(doParallel)
library(doRNG)
registerDoParallel(cores = 3)
registerDoRNG(12345)

run_tasks <- function(k, N, numVals) {
  return(matrix(runif(numVals * N), numVals, N))
}

K <- 10000
N <- 40
numVals <- 10

# Run the simulation
results <-
  foreach(k = 1:K, .combine = rbind) %dorng% run_tasks(k, N, numVals)

# Desired output format
# results <- array(NA, c(numVals, N, K))
```

Comment: You should be using `cbind` for combining.  The way R stores arrays is everything in the first column, then everything in the second, etc.  Using `cbind` will append each run at the end, which is the same storage order as a `c(numvals, N, K)` array uses.  You should be able to just change the `dim()` of the result without touching the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `foreach` returns the results in a list, so don't use `.combine` at all and make an `array` afterwards.

```
> results <- foreach(k = 1:K) %dorng% run_tasks(k, N, numVals)
> A <- array(unlist(results), dim=c(numVals, N, K))
> dim(A)
[1]  10  40 10000
> all.equal(A[,,1], results[[1]])
[1] TRUE
```

Not a frequent `foreach` user, but I think `.combine` is just a convenience argument, and instead of `.combine=rbind` you could also use `do.call('rbind', result)`. The combining is done after the multithreaded process, so using `.combine` should not have significant speed gains.